# How to build GhostScript from source for WinRT?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, ghostscript, nmake

I need the GhostScript 32-bit dll (gsdll32.dll) built to be compatible with Windows Runtime.
According GS's documentation, you can build the dll, from the [source files](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gpdldnld.html), for WinRT apps.
 See header [8.3](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.21/Make.htm).

Since I had no idea what I was getting myself into, I opened up the Ghostscript-winrt solution and tried to build it, and as you can imagine it outputted errors

[image: Build output]

The doc specifies how to build using Microsoft Visual Studio command line. But it's not very clear to the user who isn't experienced with nmake. For example,

The normal installation process for Microsoft Visual C++ includes setting the location of the Microsoft Visual C++ executables (cl.exe, link.exe, nmake.exe, rc.exe) in your PATH definition and the LIB and INCLUDE environment variables are set to point to the Microsoft Visual C++ directories. If this is true then the value for DEVSTUDIO can be changed to empty. I.e. DEVSTUDIO=

I don't know where these three environment variables are. I've the code thats called when I tried to build it:

nmake -f psi\msvc32.mak SBR=1 DEVSTUDIO= METRO=1 debug && nmake -f psi\msvc32.mak DEVSTUDIO= METRO=1 debugbsc

Any ideas based on the output what I need to set here?

Comment: Checking with the developer who originally did the port, we suspect this is simply bit-rot. The build has not been checked for a long time, years in fact, because we don't see WinRT as important for us. Most likely some code has shifted or new source files been added/old ones removed. It should be entirely possible to bring the makefile up to date, but I'm afraid you're on your own doing the work.

Comment: @KenS Any chance I could, or you could, get in contact with the developer again and inquire about the most recent dll he built for WinRT? I am not technically savvy enough to maneuver through the makefile, uncover any changes that need to be made, and fix them myself - hence the SO help inquiry.

Comment: You're welcome to ask on the #ghostscript IRC channel on freenode.net